# HQL sorting by sum of collection items' property value

Tags: hibernate, sum, hql, named

I hope someone can point me in the right direction with a Hibernate named query.

I want to sort a result based on a property of a collection item. Think it is easiest by example:

I have 2 classes: A and B

A has a property "Bs" which is a set of B.

B has a property "rank" which is an integer.

I want to query for (all) As and sort them on the sum of B.rank in A.Bs.

Something like:

```
select x from A as x order by sum(x.Bs.rank)
```

Hope this makes sense! The above query now throws an error "illegal attempt to dereference collection".

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the access to the table b manually into the select, as you have to it in SQL. In SQL you could to

```
select a.key, a.col2, a.col3, ... from a, b
   where a.key = b.foreignKeyFromA
   group by a.key, a.col2, a.col3, ...
   order by sum(b.rank);
```

Hibernate does not generate this access to B automatically, so you have to implement it manually in an HQL statement, something like this

```
select new A(a.key, a.col2, a.col3, ...) from A a join B b
   group by a.key, a.col2, a.col3, ...
   order by sum(b.rank)
```

(You need the fitting constructor for A or you can get back an array of object with the single values. The relation between A and B must be defined in your mapping; probably this already is the case.)

Remark: In the group by clause you must mention all columns which you select, even if they do not change the grouping any more (key already is unique). If you do not mention all selected columns, you'll get an error on Oracle databases. MySQL does not need this, there `group by a.key` is sufficient, but you should write HQL statements which work principally on all databases.

Comment: It is not quite working. A and B are mapped. Class A definition:

<set name="bs" table="a_b" cascade="all">
  <key column="a_id" />
  <many-to-many column="b_id" class="B" />
</set>

So I have a separate table (a_b) mapping the relationship between a and b.

Do I need select new A(), can I not use select * from A?

Many thanks for your suggestions so far.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention my database is MySQL.

Comment: If you `select new A(a.key, a.col2, ...)` then you get a list of instances of A. If you do `select a.key, col2, ...`, then you get a list of arrays of object. Both is possible, my code was more an example. But you can't `select A.*` in HQL, and it would not work with the group by (at least in Oracle). - What do you mean with "not quite working"?What exactly does not work (which error message or whoch wrong result)? - Do you really have a many-tomany relation?  In your example it also could be one-to-many, which is easier to handle.

Comment: Sorry  was a bit vague. With not quite working I meant that I get results back, but they are not sorted as required. I now have `select x from A as x join x.bs as y order by sum(y.rank) desc`

Comment: Also above I didn't mean select A.*, apologies. I meant select x from A as x which would select all columns I believe?
Yes, it is a many to many mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If A is complex or inherited, you may want to only get it's id:

```
select a.id, sum(b.rank)
from A as a join a.Bs as b
group by a.id
order by sum(b.rank)
```

Load the A's using `session.get(id)`.